# Rename tag "red-faction-guerilla" to "red-faction-guerrilla"

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The game is called [Red Faction: Guerrilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Faction:_Guerrilla) with double r. Perhaps the old version as a tag synonyme is a good idea.

Comment: I don't think misspelled words should be tag synonyms. We don't have a "rougelikes" tag, after all.

Comment: @Oak: Thank you. Can you also take a look at my other question http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1714/add-tag-for-diggles-the-myth-of-fenris ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done. I didn't see much point with leaving the old version as a synonym, since there is auto-completion for tags.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you enter an answer when a request is completed.

Comment: Right, fixed that.